# Assigning the values to the array manually in unity C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I working on a Unity Game, I converted JavaScript code to C#. I am stuck while assigning the values to an array, I works pretty fine in JavaScript but in C# it gives the following error "  error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `,' "
As i know there is no error in syntax.

**This is JavaScript code and it works fine:**

```
public var primaryPhaseDuration = 20.0;
public var transitionPhaseDuration = 3.0;


function Start () {
stateIntervals =[primaryPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,primaryPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration]; 
}
```

**Here is C# code which has the error:**

```
public float primaryPhaseDuration= 20.0f;
public float transitionPhaseDuration= 3.0f
void Start () {
    stateIntervals ={primaryPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,primaryPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration,transitionPhaseDuration}; 
}
```

I have google it but what i found was the same syntax i am using

Comment: As a quick look you've missed a `;` after this line `public float transitionPhaseDuration = 3.0f` also in C# you should define the type of the `stateIntervals` as `float[]` like this:`float[] stateIntervals ={ ...`

Comment: hmm czhange 'public float transitionPhaseDuration= 3.0f' to 'public float transitionPhaseDuration= 3.0f;'

Comment: Thank your for your quick reply, ; was missed during posting the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
stateIntervals= new float [] {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```